# Codeigniter Pagination with Material Design Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to use MDB pagination with Codeigniter's pagination library.

I am confused with the config for pagination, as i am not getting the desired results.

```
$perpage = 4;
$config['base_url'] = '/codeigniter/holiday/holidays';
$config['total_rows'] =  count($holidays);
$config['per_page'] = $perpage;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['num_links'] = 3;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-blue">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = '<li class="page-item "><a class="page-link">First</a></li>';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

The working HTML is something like this :

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-blue">
    <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">First</a></li>
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">5</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How do I set config options to get the above HTML  ?
 Currently I am getting these as result :

[image: Current Result]

Comment: and what is the result you are getting?

Comment: @Alex added in my question

Comment: image is very useful, i meant the source it is generating (just the relevant part)

Comment: @Alex yes, but I am not sure how i assign the css classes and make it look like i want it to.. I mean have a bootstrap library that styles the pagination, but not sure how to use it with codeigniter's pagination

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `Codeigniter` pagination is working properly. Only issue with pagination links styling.

This may happen if there is no styles defined in `css` for the classes you used for links. Check whether bootstrap material source file is properly included or not. Also check whether styles are defined properly in `css` for the classes you used for pagination links, for eg: `<li class="page-item">`.